# How can I access the files from admin's google drive in a google appengine app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-data-api

I wanted to access the files stored by the admin in google drive in my app engine app.

Currently I am able to access the contents in "Application Data" which is hidden and difficult to manage.

I wanted to access the files stored in admin's google drive . (which is visible and can be managed through UI https://drive.google.com/#my-drive).

(In Java)

Answer (score 0):

Either run the oauth flow to get the admin refresh token, or share the admin folder you want with the special  user that appengine has.

Comment: running oath flow everytime is not feasible. I've already shared the the folders publically. But I don't know how to access the shared files.

Comment: You haven't understood the answer from @zig. You need to run the flow one time only in order to win a refresh token. Once you have that, you can access the file without involving any user oauth flow. I suspect you think that because the file is shared public, that there is some form  of anonymous access through the Driver API. There isn't. The Drive API does NOT support anonymous access.